# Callout position problem

Tags: plotting, labeling

[image]

```
Plot[{Callout[x - 1, "x=1", {1, Above}, CalloutMarker -> "Star"],   Callout[(E - 1)*Log[x], "x=e", {E, Above},    CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"]}, {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True,  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

Why is this a bit off?
Should it not be positioned exactly at (1,0)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the third argument of `Callout` to specify the anchor position:

```
Plot[{Callout[x - 1, "x=1", {1, Above}, 1, CalloutMarker -> "Star"], 
  Callout[(E - 1)*Log[x], "x=e", {E, Above}, E, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint"]}, 
 {x, 0.5, 3.5}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]